# How to update Modules?

Tags: module, update

I'm new to EE, and I'm not a web programmer, although I can understand some very basic things, and I used to use Wordpress which is very different. So my question may sounds trivial.

**How can I update Modules in EE?**

Do I need to only upload the new folder, or do I need to do something else?
I couldn't find any tutorial about this.
I have a website with EE 2.5.3 and I would like to update the Transcribe module to take advantage of only one option in the new version.

Answer (score 2):

**Important edit: a database backup before you do any module updating might prevent data loss and is always a good idea!**

It is a pretty straight forward process. For Transcribe simply follow the official installation instructions and overwrite the currently installed module files. Find the instructions here:

https://eeharbor.com/transcribe/documentation/installation

A more general overview which might apply to most EE 2 or 3 modules: EE 2 and 3 add-ons usually come in a zip file, and the zip file contains a mixture of files and folders. All Add-ons contain a folder with the add-on itself in it - usually at the bottom of a folder stack that replicates the normal folder structure for an EE 2 or 3 installation - so for example an add-on with the name "XXX" might be at the bottom of a folder path like this (EE3 uses a slightly different directory structure):

`system/expressionengine/third_party/XXX`

To install this add-on, simply copy the folder XXX to the equivalent `expressionengine/third_party` directory on your EE server.

Some EE2 add-ons also have custom Control Panel code - so you get a customised control for the add-on within EE. For that, you also need to install another folder which is at the bottom of a different folder path (EE3 might have a different path):

`themes/third_party/XXX`

To install this, again simply copy the XXX folder to the equivalent folder on your EE installation.

Now is your last chance to do a database backup. When the replacing/overwriting of files and folders is done, go to the Add-Ons/Modules page in EE 2 or 3 and click on the button "Module Updates" (top right) - and then if necessary 'install' the add-on (by clicking on the 'install' button on the row the add-on is listed on).

HTH

Comment: Missing a few MAJOR steps in this answer.
1) What about backing up the database before updating the module? You're asking for major headaches if you don't...
2) What about checking the module requirements (EE version & PHP version)
Updating modules like this are best left to a professional.

Comment: Hello!  Thanks for the constructive comments - but I guess you missed the opening paragraph - the direction to simply follow the instructions given by eeharbour.com... I guess if you think their directions are insufficient you should take it up directly with them.  The rest was simply an outline of how you go about doing the same thing.  Yes there are many OCD steps  you can add if you want (but then answer becomes a tutorial on EE...).  Of course you could also have contributed your own answer with all the correct information in ... but I guess trolling people is easier...